# Pipe output through a bash or, double pipe, || expression?

Tags: bash, pipe

I have a noisy command whose output I want to hide on success. However, in a failure case, that output might prove helpful for debugging, so I want to show it before printing my error message.

Currently, I do it this way:

```
OUTPUT=$( cmd1 2>&1 ) || {
  echo $OUTPUT
  echo cmd1 failed
  exit 1
}
```

Is it possible to pipe `cmd1`'s output through the `||` (or, double-pipe) so I can avoid creating a variable for the output?

Comment: Nothing you'd want to actually *use*...

Comment: Any suggestion is welcome. Maybe it will give others ideas.

Comment: The only other *useful* option is to use a file instead of a variable. The **un**-useful options include named pipes/etc. that the command writes to that you then drain/close either to the screen or to `/dev/null`/etc. I believe.

Comment: You really want `echo "$OUTPUT"` in order to preserve formatting in the noisy output; otherwise, it will be even less useful.

Comment: FWIW, it seems, you’ve missed `>&2` in `echo >&2 $OUTPUT` and `echo >&2 cmd1 failed`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to save the output of the command *somewhere* because you don't know until the command finishes whether or not to send the output to the console. Piping the output to something won't help, since pipes don't have large buffers.

You have a few options for buffering, but using a variable is a reasonable one if you don't expect megabytes of output, which would go well beyond the definition of `noisy`. You could also use a temporary file, but there are few advantages to that unless you're intending to deploy on a system with very limited memory (by today's standards).

Comment: That makes sense. I just hoped there was some incantation of bash where you could disable pipe buffering and allow the output to cross the `||` boundary.

Comment: @HeathBorders: I think you misunderstand what `||` does. `a || b` means "do `a` (completely). If it didn't succeed, do `b`". There is no buffering involved. By the time `b` runs, if it does, `a` has finished. So if you want to pass the output of `a` into `b`, you need to buffer it. In other words, you are not looking for an incantation which *disables* buffering; you are looking for an incantation which *enables* it. And you already know how to do that: use a variable as the buffer.

Comment: @HeathBorders: The fact that `(a || b)` produces the output of `a` is not the result of that output being buffered somewhere and then resent: it is the result of both `a` and `b` having their output redirected to the output of the disjunction. Consequently, the output of `a` appears *immediately*. Example: `(echo line 1; sleep 1; echo line 2; exit 1) || echo "The other command failed"`. Could you predict how that would work before you ran it?

Comment: I understand. My original comment was poorly worded. Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

Try the:

```
OUT=$(command....) && OUT= || { echo $OUT; exit 1;}
```

- the `&&` executed when the result of the command is `OK` (exit 0)
- and clearing the OUT

Comment: That's a good idea, but I'm trying to avoid having to use a variable at all. I'm not worried about clearing the variable if the command succeeds.

Answer (score 1):

Joey Hess' [moreutils](https://joeyh.name/code/moreutils/package) has a command [`chronic(1)`](http://manned.org/chronic/19499fb8) which does precisely what you want: it runs a command, eating its `stdout` and `stderr`, *unless* the command exits non-zero, in which case the output is passed through.